# Restkit resources mapping depending on parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm strating to use RetKit, but documentation could be better.

How can I register mappings for resources relying on request parameter?
Unfortunatelly I don't have well written service to consume, so that all my resources are in `somexamplepath.com/api/` but asking about one is done by parameter like:
`somexamplepath.com/api/?res=people` or `somexamplepath.com/api/?res=machines`

What is the best way to do mappings for such situation?

Answer (score 2):

This situation is not well covered because RestKit matches against URL paths, not query parameters.

You could use multiple instances of `RKObjectManager` where each instance is to be used for a particular subset of your API content.

I haven't tried this, but it may be possible to setup a 2 stage process where the URL path is used to match initially and that takes you to an `RKDynamicMapping`. In the dynamic mapping you can then use `RKObjectMappingMatcher` which gives access to predicate based matching using `matcherWithPredicate:objectMapping:`. If the `@metadata.URL` key is available to the predicate you can match all of the query parameters there.

Answer (score 1):

you are talking about the same resource with different query strings. Just add the query string parameter when you send the request.. ie

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"res":@"people"};
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"api/" 
                                       parameters:params
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation,
                                                    RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
     // blah blah
```

---

here is a more comprehensive example from my own code.. i totally understand the whole "documentation could be better".. notice i have two entity mappings (for two different entities).. event and attendee:

```
// Configure the object manager
_objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com/api/v1"]];
_objectManager.managedObjectStore = _managedObjectStore;

[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:_objectManager];

_objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType=RKMIMETypeJSON;

RKEntityMapping *eventEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectStore:_managedObjectStore];
[eventEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                    @"id":             @"id",
                                                    @"resource_uri":   @"resource_uri",
                                                    @"title":          @"title",
                                                    @"city":           @"city",
                                                    @"from_date":      @"from_date",
                                                    @"user":           @"user_id"}];

eventEntityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"id" ];



RKResponseDescriptor *eventResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:eventEntityMapping pathPattern:@"event/" keyPath:@"objects" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[_objectManager addResponseDescriptor:eventResponseDescriptor];

RKEntityMapping *attendeeEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Attendee" inManagedObjectStore:_managedObjectStore];
[attendeeEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                               @"id":                     @"id",
                                               @"order.first_name":       @"first_name",
                                               @"order.last_name":        @"last_name",
                                               @"unique":        @"order_ticket_unique_code",
                                               @"ticket.event":           @"event_id",
                                               @"ticket.description":     @"ticket_description",
                                               @"ticket.perk":            @"ticket_perk",
                                               @"ticket.price":           @"ticket_price"}];

attendeeEntityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"id" ];



RKResponseDescriptor *attendeeResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:attendeeEntityMapping pathPattern:@"orderticket/search/" keyPath:@"objects" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
_objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType=RKMIMETypeJSON;

[_objectManager addResponseDescriptor:attendeeResponseDescriptor];
```

later on i simply fetch an attendee resource (in the api it's called orderticket.. whatever)

```
- (void)downloadAttendees
{

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"q":_eventId};
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"orderticket/search/" parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"An Error Has Occurred" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];
}
```

and i also fetch an event resource (event resource don't take a query string):

```
- (void)downloadEvents
{
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"event/" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"An Error Has Occurred" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];
}
```

Comment: lemme know if you want to see an example of how i set the up the whole resource above..as far as wain's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18550519/766570).. i'd try out the basic stuff first before venturing out to the more complex stuff

Comment: In my case it's not the same resource. `somexamplepath.com/api/?res=people` should be mapped to entity `Person`, whereas `somexamplepath.com/api/?res=machines` to entity `Machine` so probably Wain's is more appropriate here.

Comment: Well in that case you should either at least vote him up.. Or tell him why his answer falls short..

Comment: I'll like always. Just I haven't got time yet to test it.